# How do I compare 2 arrays element by element?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, containers, bitwise-operators

[Arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwSFU.png)

I want to compare element by element the 2 arrays and print them side by side. 
The element comparison would be and AND comparison. (i.e 0&1=0,0&0=0,1&1=1)

```
int main()
{
ifstream inFile;
int array1[10][10], array2[10][10];
int rows, cols;
OpenInputFile(inFile);

ReadData(rows, cols, array1, array2, inFile);

cout << "Initial values of the arrays processed" << endl;
cout << string(50,'-') << endl;
cout << setw(2*cols) << left << "Array1";
cout << setw(2*cols) << left << "Array2" << endl;;  
PrintArray(array1, rows, cols),PrintArray(array2, rows, cols);
}
```

Comment: And what is the question? Show at least the array definitions.

Comment: Your textual representation of the arrays was much better. Don't link to images that can be represented as text.

Comment: You know how to loop through the matrix, since you can print them. And you know what a bitwise comparison is. Why don't you just loop through both arrays and do a bitwise comparison of each element and its corresponding buddy in the other matrix?

Comment: I want to compare Row1 Element 1 in Array1 with Row 1 Element 1 in Array2. I am trying to compare the arrays like AND, OR, and XNOR logic gates and print the results.

Comment: As awkward as it is to use for much beyond this, `std::valarray` seems like a good fit. It's specifically designed for doing element-wise operations and supports the bit manipulation operators.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    int a1[N] = 
    {
        0b10101, 0b01010, 0b10100, 0b00111   
    };

    int a2[N] = 
    {
        0b11100, 0b00110, 0b11111, 0b10001
    };

    int a3[N];
    int a4[N];

    std::transform( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ),
                    std::begin( a2 ),
                    std::begin( a3 ),
                    std::bit_and<int>() );

    std::transform( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ),
                    std::begin( a2 ),
                    std::begin( a4 ),
                    std::bit_or<int>() );


    std::cout << std::hex;                
    for ( const auto &item : a1 )
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << item << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &item : a2 )
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << item << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &item : a3 )
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << item << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &item : a4 ) 
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << item << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
15 0a 14 07 
1c 06 1f 11 
14 02 14 01 
1d 0e 1f 17
```

**Edit:** after you edited your question changing one-dimensional arrays to two-dimensional arrays then you can use the shown calls of the algorithm for each pair of "rows" of the source arrays in a loop.

For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    std::transform( std::begin( a1[i] ), std::end( a1[i] ),
                    std::begin( a2[i] ),
                    std::begin( a3[i] ),
                    std::bit_and<int>() );
}
```